# iOS App Store Developers - What is the 'copyright name' of an app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I understand that whenever you upload a new app, you can set the copyright name for the app.

**Where is this name displayed?**

Is this name displayed underneath the name of the app when searching in the app store? Or is that the seller name that you specify when you upload your first app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the line next to the © sign, usually the last line under the app icon on AppStore.

Answer (score -6):

I think you can think of "trademark", which serves to identify a particular iPhone app or any service. You can register a TRADEMARK for your name.
But unless you pay to register it then you have no rights to it. So according to me for all iOS app developer rather mobile app developer must think of trademark for copyright name of an app.
Thanks

Comment: A trademark is something completely different.